# How to run an app from cmd in one line

Tags: c, cmd

I am trying to make a c program that will open my internet apps e.g. chrome, thunderbird etc.
When i am using the

```
system("")
```

function i have to do it all in one line cause everytime i reuse it, it resets my directory to where the c project is saved.
How is that possible?

Comment: Are you using a linux based system? Then the directory does not matter

Comment: Why don't you write a very simple shell script?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: why not? Windows and Linux both have `path` environment variables which contains the default folders to search for the file if you don't specify the path. If the file isn't in any path then the return is just error

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: In a linux terminal, any software can be opened from any directory without the use of a path. but the same does not apply in a windows system. That was what i said

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: no, in Linux the program must also be in the `path` or have a path attached. You can run most of the apps directly because they are placed in `/usr/bin` or some system folders like that. There's nothing prevent you from installing/copying the running file to any other folder or remove the `/usr/bin` from the `path` environment variable

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc But since the OP wants programs like chrome and Thunderbird, the path is not necessary for such applications right?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: No. He said "e.g. chrome, thunderbird etc", not a specific program. And it's also not certain that the needed folder are in the `path`. Anyone can remove it from the path list or force the program to install into a different folder

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: So if the path is dynamic, how can the C program locate it?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: If the user didn't do as default then he must provide the path explicitly. If not, and the program gets an error, that's his fault

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc So that eliminates the use of this c program.. Instead of compiling it, running it, and then opening the app, he can simply use the terminal right?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: why needed the terminal? He can specify the path in the system function, or if needed search the path in the program. Anyway I don't talk about this, what I said is your sentence "In a linux terminal, any software can be opened from any directory without the use of a path" is wrong. End discussion

Comment: My bad, I have windows. (and linux but the program i want to make is intended for windows) Anyhow i solved my problem! Thank you all for the fast response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend on what system & shell you're on, the syntax may be different

On Windows cmd [just use `&&` or `&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). For example

```
notepad && mspaint
calc & dir
```

`&&` will run the second command if the first completed successfully. `&` will run the command in the background on Linux/Unix, whereas it'll run the first then the second command in Windows